# sudo error permission denied

Tags: command-line, sudo

I have started few days ago with Ubuntu Server and I've got a weird error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu: $ sudo -s
sudo: /var/lib/sudo/ubuntu/ is accessible in write mode from not-owner (040777), should have modality 0700
```

Translated from the Italian message:

```
sudo: /var/lib/sudo/ubuntu è accessibile in scrittura dal non-proprietario (040777) dovrebbe avere la modalità 0700
```

---

This is the results:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu: $ pkexec chmod 0700 /var/lib/sudo/


==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org. freedesktop.policykit.exe ===

Authentication is needed to run '/bin/chmod' as the super user
Authenticating as: ubuntu,,, (ubuntu)
Password:


==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
```

i also tried with "sudo" but it doesn't work....

i would like post the image,but i can't sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the below command to fix the broken sudo -

```
sudo chmod 0755 /var/lib/sudo

sudo chmod 0700 /var/lib/sudo/<username>
```

If the above command doesn't helps, you can run the below command :

```
pkexec chmod 0755 /var/lib/sudo

pkexec chmod 0700 var/lib/sudo/<username>
```

Comment: Have edited OPs response back into question.